# Using HSCAN for pagination

Tags: redis

I have a large `HSET` in Redis and would like to have an API to browse through it with pagination. The obvious candidate would be using `HSCAN` with a cursor, so that API users would pass it back to fetch the next batch of records. I'm afraid, however, that if a new entry is added to the hash in between, the ordering could be messed up and cursor will become invalid (similar to how iterators break once you update a hash during the iteration).

Is my concern valid? If not, why? If yes, are there any workarounds, or will I have to change the storage approach?

Comment: Yes, you have to change the storage approach. Say, using LIST or ZSET.

Comment: @for_stack I am now reading [this piece of docs](https://redis.io/commands/scan/#scan-guarantees), and it says that `SCAN` guarantees to return everything (except, maybe some things multiple times). It doesn't mention if it applies to `HSCAN` though, and `HSCAN` docs refer to `SCAN`. So it's a bit confusing.

Comment: I am pretty sure that the behaviour described for `SCAN` does apply to `HSCAN`.

Comment: @bereal Yes, it applies to HSCAN too. However, since it might return items multiple times, I don't think it's a good idea to implement pagination with HSCAN. Otherwise, you might see the same item in the same page, or in multiple pages.